# Python requests how to use cursor to get every page

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get every page and write it to a JSON. This is what I have and it writes fine to a JSON but it only writes the first 100 and doesn't cursor to each page. This is the api https://developers.gfycat.com/api/#user-feeds

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.gfycat.com/v1/users/brandonedora/gfycats"

params = {"count": "100", "cursor": "YnJhbmRvbmVkb3JhfDEsdmlnb3JvdXNkZWZpYW50ZG9iZXJtYW5waW5zY2hlcixicmFuZG9uZWRvcmEsMTU4NDYxNDQ5Mg=="}

r = requests.get(url, params=params)

text_json = json.loads(r.content)

json.dump(text_json, open("testdump.json", "w"), indent = 2)
```

Comment: pay attention for `The last cursor received from the API to use for paging resuts`

Comment: Would I use the one that's at the top of the JSON?

Comment: loop using the last one ! check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
import json


params = {
    "count": "100",
    "cursor": "YnJhbmRvbmVkb3JhfDEsdmlnb3JvdXNkZWZpYW50ZG9iZXJtYW5waW5zY2hlcixicmFuZG9uZWRvcmEsMTU4NDYxNDQ5Mg=="
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        allin = []
        for _ in range(1, 4):
            r = req.get(url, params=params).json()
            params['cursor'] = r['cursor']
            print(params)

            allin.append(r)
        goal = json.dumps(allin, indent=4)
        with open("data.txt", 'w') as f:
            f.write(goal)


main("https://api.gfycat.com/v1/users/brandonedora/gfycats")
```

Comment: How would I write the output to a JSON?

Comment: How would I write it to a json file I tried `print(df.to_json(r"testjson.json"))` and it only did 0 - 99. I also tried `df.to_json((r"testjson.json"), indent = 2)` and that did 0 - 99 as well

Comment: I'm sorry but it still only writes 0-99

Comment: I got it to work but I just realized this is only duplicating the data from the first cursor. If you ctrl-f and search one of the gfyNumbers it shows the same data 4 times

Comment: It works now thank you very much but it seems to be skipping the first page.The first one is https://giant.gfycat.com/CraftyFrigidArachnid.mp4 and when I go to the gfycat profile that's about the 100th gif .The first one should be https://giant.gfycat.com/HugeTiredGoral.mp4

Comment: It doesn't work it still starts at the same one. When I go to https://api.gfycat.com/v1/users/brandonedora/gfycats?count=100 the first one is https://giant.gfycat.com/HugeTiredGoral.mp4

Comment: well, you have to read the documentation and check from which number the count start. anyway it's starts from 1